# How to disable saving HTML snapshots of pages for failed tests in Codeception?

Tags: codeception

When my acceptance tests fail, I usually only need the screenshots of a page. HTML output clutters the output directory and makes it difficult to navigate to the screenshots. Is there a command line argument or a configuration option to disable HTML output completely?